# This error keeps on coming everytime i run react-native run-android after npm install

Tags: android, react-native

Task :react-native-google-places:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-google-places:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :react-native-google-places
  >   Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' that satisfies the version constraints:
  >       Dependency path 'FastGo:react-native-google-places:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.3' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

In the android/app/build.gradle file, specify the compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion as,

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Also make sure that you have installed SDK API level 26.